# Is it correct to say "I will listen to your words and correct them for you"?

Tags: word-choice

My friend has an interview in English next week and he wants me to record all what he says and correct any mistakes he makes (English grammar or vocabulary).

Is it correct to say "*I will listen to your words/ talk/ talking/ speaking/ voice/ sentences/ saying/ text/ speech.. and correct them for you*"?

I feel like "**your words/ talk/ talking/ speaking**" sounds good but I am not sure which is suitable for the above situation.

Comment: I find the use of the / sign in the manner you have here to be jarring and annoying. My suggestion is to pick the best word and use it.

Comment: When you listen to someone, they are using words, and they are talking, so it's redundant to add anything else. *I'll **listen** to you and **pinpoint** (correct) any errors you might make.*

Comment: @BillOnne  The OP is not proposing to use "/", rather he or she is asking posters here to chose one of those alternatives. This use of "/" is common on ELL, although officially discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

> I will listen to your words and correct them for you

expresses the thought without any need for participles or other supplement. Moreover, some of your supplements are not grammatical, for example

> I will listen to your words talk

is not grammatical. “Talk” denotes a physical activity that words are unable to perform, at least not literally. In idiomatic English, what you mean is

> I shall listen to what you say and correct any errors.

To be frank, I am not sure your corrections will persuade any native speaker of English that it is your friend’s native tongue. But presumably they know that **already.**

Answer (score 0):

None of your example nouns sound very natural - that's just not the best way to express this in English.

Better:

> I will listen to you speak and suggest corrections.